# Por que no me funciona el llamado a un método que genera un aleatorio al ponerlo en un ciclo?

Tags: java, android, bucles

El siguiente código en Android funciona bien, se manda llamar a una imagen y realiza una pausa, quiero que esto funciones varias veces, por lo que para empezar metí al método **fotos1()** en un ciclo `for` como lo muestro al final pero no me funciona, siempre muestra la misma foto, pareciera que no hay mas fotos, no cambia, como puede hacer para que funcione mostrando distintas fotos?

```
private void fotos1() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        int n;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int aleatorio;

            aleatorio=(int)(Math.random()*3);
            titulo.setText(String.valueOf(aleatorio));
            imagenes.setImageResource(mis_fotos[aleatorio]);

        }
    },3000);
}
```

Código del ciclo

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    fotos1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener un numero aleatorio puedes usar:

```
int  aleatorio = new Random().nextInt((maximo - minimo) + 1) + minimo;
```

Estableciendo como `minimo` el indice menor que sería 0 y como `maximo` puedes definir la medida del array, por lo tanto esta sería la forma correcta de obtener un valor aleatorio del array `mis_fotos` :

```
private void fotos1() {

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        int n;
        @Override
        public void run() {

          int  aleatorio = new Random().nextInt((mis_fotos.length - 0) + 1) + 0;
          titulo.setText(String.valueOf(aleatorio));
          imagenes.setImageResource(mis_fotos[aleatorio]);

        }
    },3000);
}
```